# Regular expression for date time format “MM/DD HH:mm AM/PM”?

Tags: php, regex, date, time, preg-replace

Can anyone tell me a regex to preg_replace all timestamps from a log file? The format is below. Leading zero's on month and day, not on hour.

```
05/05 : 5:00 PM or MM/DD : HH:mm AM/PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex to match that is as follows:

```
/[01][0-9]\/[0-3]?[0-9] : 1?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9] (A|P)M/
```

The appropriate syntax for `preg_replace` or the like would depend on how you want the replacement to look.

Comment: Works, perfect, except one minor thing, i realized the days do NOT have leading zero's, i tried modifying the expression with no luck, however if you could update it ive saved a copy so i can see what changes you made as to learn a bit more. Ive also included the basic preg_replace i ended up using for reference of future readers.

`$data = preg_replace('/[01][0-9]\/[0-3][0-9] : 1?[0-9]:[0-5][0-9] (A|P)M: /', '', $data);`

Comment: @ryan - Updated, and not a problem. I highly recommend you spend an hour or two learning about regular expressions... they can be insanely useful in many situations.

Comment: It will accept 0am, 0pm, 13am to 19am  and 13pm to 19pm !